# getting directly a specific nested json object inside other json objects

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
    "continue": {
        "rvcontinue": "20200228224232|943114133",
        "continue": "||"
    },
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "16152986": {
                "pageid": 16152986,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Eden Hazard",
                "revisions": [
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2020-02-28T22:53:59Z"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way using java to get directly timestamp value without parsing others json values (particulary "16152986")?

Comment: i don't think that is possible without parsing the json file. any other third party library will use parsing, please specify to us why you want to do this without parsing ??

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole json file as a String and then use regex to extract the timestamp value from the whole String

```
^.*\"timestamp\": "(.*)".*$
```